# Siddhi CEP 3.x newbie questions

Tags: siddhi

I'm new to Siddhi, and I got several questions:

1. Is **SiddhiManager** thread safe?  Is it a good practice one shared instance per JVM?
2. How to define stream and add query at runtime?   It seems it only has **siddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(plan)** which will create a new **ExecutionPlanRuntime** instance. And how to redefine stream and query?
3. What's **inEvents**  and **removeEvents** in **QueryCallback**?

   ```
    executionPlanRuntime.addCallback("query1", new QueryCallback() {
           @Override
           public void receive(long timeStamp, Event[] inEvents, Event[] removeEvents) {
               EventPrinter.print(timeStamp, inEvents, removeEvents);
           }
       });
   ```
4. How would Siddhi scale, if I have lots of stream and queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. SiddhiManager is Thread safe and it is a good practice to have
   one shared instance per JVM. In-fact that is how Siddhi Manager is
   used in WSO2 CEP.
2. In Siddhi stream definition + query combination is considered as an
   Execution Plan. There is no dedicated way to edit an execution plan
   at Siddhi level other than re-deploying that using
   createExecutionPlan method. Please note that you will get a new
   ExecutionPlanRuntime object by this. Hence can not reuse old input
   handler references.
3. inEvents array represents current-events emitted by Siddhi and
   removeEvents represent expired-events emitted by Siddhi
4. Siddhi will scale quite well if you have lot of queries in single
   execution plan. But when scaling out with multiple execution plans
   Siddhi will hit the resource threshold quickly since resource
   utilization is little high per execution plan which will result in performance degredation. 
   Recently we made an improvement to address this limitation as
   explained in this[1] mail. Improvement is available in master
   branch.

[1] http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Siddhi-Making-Disruptor-configurable-td136499.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful!  Any plan to support edit an execution plan at runtime?  Or you think this is useless perhaps?

Comment: Feature to hot deploy is indeed useful, but we have compromised it for the sake of performance. If we are to support hot query swapping there should be a mechanism to prevent loosing events which received during swapping process. This will add a layer of code to the critical path of execution. If we think about the probability of someone hot swapping execution plans at runtime in a production system, it is very minimal. Perhaps zero even. So we are basically trading off. That is the reason behind not pursuing a hot deploy solution.